# How to List All Virtual Hosts in Apache Web Server installed on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS?

Tags: apache2

How may I enable all the Virtual Hosts in Apache Web Server and know if they are enabled or not?

Comment: That does not appear to be a question about Ubuntu.  Seems the question would be better asked here. https://httpd.apache.org/support.html

Comment: you are right however --> After googling it a bit more I have found out that a few different ways are out there to list them all but the one that works on Ubuntu is : sudo apache2ctl  -S. Every bit of the syntax must be as-is or you will get an error, so I feel it should remain here, but may be I should edit the question to include Ubuntu server in the title.  I as an Ubuntu user, I always come here first and had someone asked it here, it would have saved me about 30 minutes which is a lot given that I am at work.

Comment: Did not ask you to remove it. I suggested that you might get an answer at other site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Ubuntu this version works best and produces a list of all sites enabled and their aliases

```
 sudo apache2ctl -S
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also run below one liner script for listing all enabled current hosted webiste in ubuntu apache. this will show output accordingly.

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ && echo -e "\nListing all enabled website and its home directory for server $(hostname -I):-\n$(cat $(ls) |grep -i 'ServerName\|DocumentRoot')\nReport Timestamp:- $(TZ='Asia/Kolkata' date)\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need more details, [what @Max suggested](https://askubuntu.com/a/1329802/1157209) is a very good solution:

```
sudo apache2ctl -S
```

However, if you need brief info, you can use this:

```
sudo a2query -s
```